# How can I configure VCR to use cassette names that match the request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, vcr

I am using rspec/capybara/VCR to record tapes. Currently my tapes are automatically named to include a simplified version of the hierarchy of the test that is being run, as is the default.

I would like to configure the cassette naming scheme so that it is dependent instead on the parameters of the request, so any PUT to /abc.com with a body of XYZ would use the same tape. My thought was to configure VCR with this:

```
config.around_http_request do |request|
  tape_name = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest [request.method, request.uri, request.headers.to_s, request.body.to_s].join('')
  puts "Using tape #{tape_name}"
  puts "on = #{VCR.turned_on?}"
  VCR.use_cassette(tape_name, :record => :new_episodes, &request)
end
```

But when I do that, eventually I get the errors such as:

```
There is already a cassette with the same name (5d971f35322c4e0cf7d379aa39a28ef12994552f).  You cannot nest multiple cassettes with the same name.
```

How can I name tapes with what they contain and prevent this error?

Comment: It looks like it's called twice with the exact same `[request.method, request.uri, request.headers.to_s, request.body.to_s]`.

Comment: Please explain, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If there's a cassette with the exat same name "5d971f35322c4e0cf7d379aa39a28ef12994552f", it means that this hash has already been calculated. A collision is very unlikely, so a previous call with the exact same `request` must have been done.

Comment: Right but in that case, shouldn't it be using that tape rather than trying to make a new one?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used VCR.

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced the same problem and it seems that the root cause was that cassettes somehow got nested during some requests (i.e. like using a `VCR.use_cassette('whatever')` inside another `VCR.use_cassette('whatever')` block). So, I tried to put an `eject_cassette` prior to `use_cassette` and it seems to work fine, e.g. in this case:

```
VCR.eject_cassette(tape_name)
VCR.use_cassette(tape_name, :record => :new_episodes, &request)
```